Get rid of indentation made by `pagedown::crome_print()`
When doing RevealJS slides with Quarto, I'm using the pagedown::chrome_print() function to convert the slides to PDF format. This works pretty well, however, code chunks are getting an indentation that I can't seem to get rid off. Below is a simple example showing first the .html slide and then the .pdf slide. Is there a way to get rid of that rather large indentation?



Why do you need pagedown::chrome_print() to convert the slides to PDF format? Instead, you may try the quarto way.

@Shafee: Because I'd like to use a script to do it. In any case, "the quarto way" is doing exactly the same, that is, using Chrome to make the print, so the result is the same.

Fixed as of v. 1.5 of Quarto.
